# Solving math and got a different output from Python and Wolfram Alpha

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, wolframalpha

I found this picture on 9gag and I decided to write a python code to see if this is true

[image]

However, when I run the following python code, I got a different result from what I got from Wolfram Alpha

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return  (18111/2)*(x**4) - 90555*(x**3) + (633885/2)*(x**2) - 452773*x + 217331

for i in range(0,5):
    print f(i)
```

Output:

```
217331
0
-7
-40
-129
217016
```

And here's the link to my Wolfram Alpha query
[link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%20%3D%20%2818111%2F2%29*%28x**4%29%20-%2090555*%28x**3%29%20%2B%20%28633885%2F2%29*%28x**2%29%20-%20452773*x%20%2B%20217331%2C%20solve%20f%281%29%2C%20f%282%29%2C%20f%283%29%2C%20f%284%29%2C%20f%285%29)

Notice that I copied and pasted my equation string directly from my Python code to Wolfram alpha and it seems to interpreted correctly. So I highly doubt that the fault is within my Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2.x, `int / int` returns a `int`. (truncate number below decimal point)

```
>>> 18111/2
9055
```

To get the number you want, you need to use `float`.

```
>>> 18111/2.0
9055.5
```

Or, you can change the behavior using [`from __future__ import ...` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html):

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 18111 / 2
9055.5
```

---

BTW, to iterate from 1 to 5. you need to use `range(1, 6)`, not `range(0, 5)`.

```
>>> range(0, 5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> range(1, 6)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I should have noticed that, there were so many time that I had issues with Python's datatypes.